# Spring Boot + React CORS issue without spring security

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, cors

I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE as a REST service and React for front-end.

Just a simple GET method implemented, But getting CORS issue when communicating to the server via REACT.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/ -> followed this link, but no luck.

my Spring Boot Controller:

```
@RestController
public class FeedController {
    @Autowired
    private IFeedService IFeedService;

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @GetMapping(path="/v1/getdashboard")
    public ResponseEntity<String> feedDashBoardController(){
        String result = null;
        HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
        try {

             List<FeedData> dashBoardFeedInfo = IFeedService.getDashBoardFeedService();

             // Create ObjectMapper
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonNode dataNode = mapper.valueToTree(dashBoardFeedInfo);

            result = FeedResponseData.generateFeedResponse(dataNode);
            httpStatus = HttpStatus.OK;

        }catch(TBServiceException e) {
            result = AppExceptions.handleException("Something Went Wrong");
            httpStatus = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<String>(result,httpStatus);
    }
}
```

my Spring Boot Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TechnicalBlogApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TechnicalBlogApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("Application Main - Update -1");

    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/v1/getdashboard").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

my Spring application properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
server.port=6001
server.servlet.context-path=/technical-blog
```

my React Code Snippet:

```
async componentDidMount() {
const dashboardData= await fetch("http://localhost:6001/technical-blog/v1/getdashboard");

console.log("dash ",dashboardData)
}
```

I have also tried setting the headers, below is the re-modified controller. i got multi CORS definition error.

```
@RestController
public class FeedController {
@Autowired
private IFeedService IFeedService;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@GetMapping(path="/v1/getdashboard")
public ResponseEntity<String> feedDashBoardController(){
    String result = null;
    HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
    try {

         List<FeedData> dashBoardFeedInfo = IFeedService.getDashBoardFeedService();

         // Create ObjectMapper
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode dataNode = mapper.valueToTree(dashBoardFeedInfo);

        result = FeedResponseData.generateFeedResponse(dataNode);
        httpStatus = HttpStatus.OK;

    }catch(TBServiceException e) {
        result = AppExceptions.handleException("Something Went Wrong");
        httpStatus = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<String>(result,setHeaders(),httpStatus);
}
}

private HttpHeaders setHeaders() {
    List<HttpMethod> allowedMethods = new ArrayList<>();
    allowedMethods.add(HttpMethod.GET);
    allowedMethods.add(HttpMethod.POST);

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    //httpHeaders.setAccessControlAllowOrigin("*");
    httpHeaders.setAccessControlAllowCredentials(true);
    httpHeaders.setAccessControlAllowMethods(allowedMethods);
    httpHeaders.setAccessControlMaxAge(3600);
    return httpHeaders;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should put `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")` on the controller it self because the first thing that request goes to is the controller not the function

so it will be like that

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
public class FeedController {
@Autowired
private IFeedService IFeedService;


@GetMapping(path="/v1/getdashboard")
public ResponseEntity<String> feedDashBoardController(){
    String result = null;
    HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
    try {

         List<FeedData> dashBoardFeedInfo = IFeedService.getDashBoardFeedService();

         // Create ObjectMapper
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode dataNode = mapper.valueToTree(dashBoardFeedInfo);

        result = FeedResponseData.generateFeedResponse(dataNode);
        httpStatus = HttpStatus.OK;

    }catch(TBServiceException e) {
        result = AppExceptions.handleException("Something Went Wrong");
        httpStatus = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<String>(result,setHeaders(),httpStatus);
}
}
```

Comment: do you want me to set the headers? It is not working this way.

Comment: not the header, i am talking about the request itself when it comes to the server side the first thing to do is to match the url and to do that it goes to every controller and match the prefix route and to do that it should be allowed to do that